# Grails unit or integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, junit, integration-testing

I don't know whether to use unit or integration tests for what I am wanting to test in my Grails 2.2.3 application. I want to run some tests against like this:

```
@TestFor(Student)
@Mock(Student)
class StudentTests {

void testFoundStudent() {
        def s = Student.findById(myId)
        assert s != null
        assert s.firstName = 'Grant'
        assert s.lastName = 'McConnaughey'
    }
}
```

This is going to require the use of our test database, so would that make it an integration test? When I run this code as a unit test it fails at `assert s != null`. Which means it isn't using our database, because it SHOULD find a student with that ID.

Comment: Is your test database mentioned/used in `DataSource.groovy` under `test` environment?

Comment: plus I don't think you need `@Mock` annotation if your are using `@TestFor(DomainClass)`. `@TestFor` would do the mocking for you.

Comment: where you able to resolve you issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Grails unit test you can test domain class interactions using Gorm and behind the scene Grails will use in-memory database(an implementation of a ConcurrentHashMap) to mimic this behavior [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing). So yes you get null because that student does not exist in in-memory database and you need to insert that data first.

```
Student.findOrSaveWhere (firstName: 'Grant',lastName : 'McConnaughey')
```

In your example, if the intention is to test the existence of that data you need to use integration test and connect it to your database using `datasource.groovy` , which is really not a good idea unless you have a good reason to test your data.

If you are trying to test `def s = Student.findById(myId)` again that is not adding any value as that is Grails dynamic finder and you probably need to trust the framework you are using.

However, in general

> Unit tests are typically run without the presence of physical
>   resources that involve I/O such databases, socket connections or
>   files [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing)

I hope this helps

Comment: So is it likely that an application might only need Integration tests?

Comment: I would say any application should have at least unit, integration and functional test. I would rather have overlap coverage than not covering something. You chose the test, depending on the nature of the module you are testing. Simple and naive answer, is cover your smaller components with single functionality with unit test. And then use integration test to cover their interaction and finally functional to cover bigger picture. My analogy is you zoom in and test the problem with unit test and zoom out a bit and test with integration and zoom out completely of the problem for functional test.