# grails DataSource in Unit Test

Tags: grails, datasource, grails-orm

I'm trying to bootstrap some data into the in-memory H2 database for use in a domain and service mock test.  Here is how I have the test environment's datasource configured:

```
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;INIT=runscript from 'sample_bootstrap_data.sql'"
    }
}
```

I am able to do a run-app, access the dbconsole and see all of the data. The problem I'm having is in the service test, with accessing this data.  I have a question: How would I access this data in the pre-initialized schema in a unit test?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657588/grails-unit-or-integration-tests/17658091#17658091

Comment: in short, Grails unit test implements a map that simulates Gorm database interactions. To access data in your test you need to write integration test not unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unit testing are tests at the "unit" level. In other words you are
>   testing individual methods or blocks of code without consideration for
>   surrounding infrastructure. Unit tests are typically run without the
>   presence of physical resources that involve I/O such databases, socket
>   connections or files. This is to ensure they run as quick as possible
>   since quick feedback is important.

Refer [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing).

You have to use @Mock or @Build.

Comment: I'm beyond the domain object mocking stage and I want to use data in the in-memory H2 database to perform some tests on a service.  So the correct way to approach testing this service would likely be moving it to an integration test, yes?

Then I can do

def someTrucks = Truck.findAllByWeight(5)

Comment: @ThomasFarvour Yes exactly.